# Using Net::HTTP, how can you store the url that you queried?

Tags: ruby, net-http

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

@url = 'http://foobar.com'
@query_string = {foo1: 'bar1', foo2: 'bar2'}

@post_data = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(@url), @query_string)
@request = # ? How can I get the request URL + query?
@response = @post_data.body
```

Does anyone know how you can get the actual URL that you queried, not just the response?

i.e. I want to store this in a variable to record what was sent:

http://foobar.com?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2

Comment: Since it's a post request isn't your url just the return of `URI.parse(@url)`?

Comment: I want the query string in addition to the url though.  And the query variable is a hash.

Comment: But because it's a post request the query data isn't going to be part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's not getting it from the response itself (I don't think there is a way to do this with net/http), but you can get the variable you want by doing this:

```
@request = URI.parse(@url).tap{|x|x.query=URI.encode_www_form(@query_string)}.to_s
# => "http://foobar.com?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2"
```

Comment: I ended up using the hash method "to_query" in ruby on rails.  Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to look into Ruby's URI Module:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Not sure, but you could probably get away with something like:

```
query_string = URI.encode_www_form(@query_string).to_s
record_of_uri = "#{@url}/?#{query_string}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Noting that a post request doesn't send it's params in the url, to compose `@request` as described use:

```
@request = URI.escape(@url + '?' + URI.encode_www_form(@query_string))
```